# fiona writing geometry into shapefile problem

Tags: python, geometry, shapely, fiona

**Context:**

---

I use `lxml` library that generates some dictionary (infact it is xml attribute dictionary) from xml and i am trying to write these into a shapefile-i.e. get one element-attribute from xml and write it into shapefile (using below function) then get next xml element-attribute and write it into shapefile and so on..

Below is the function that takes some parameters and writes point or polyline geometry based on passed parameters.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg

def single_geom_writer(ls,att_dict,feat_type):
    #Create geometry when called
    def geom_setter(ls):
        if len(*ls)==2:
            my_geom = Point(ls)
        elif len(*ls)>2:
            my_geom = LineString(ls)
        else:
            raise Exception("Can not handle writing geometry")
        return my_geom

    # Define a schema when called
    def schema_setter(feat_type):
        if feat_type=='lane':
            sch = {
                'geometry': geom_setter(ls).geom_type,
                'properties':{'id': 'str','index':'str','speed':'str','length':'str','width':'str'},
                  }
        elif feat_type=='junction':
            sch = {
                'geometry': geom_setter(ls).geom_type,
                'properties': {'intLanes': 'str', 'junction_shape': 'str', 'incLanes': 'str', 'y': 'str', 'x': 'str', 'type': 'str', 'id': 'str'},
                  }

        else:
            raise Exception("Schema error! Check the passed schema with collection schema")
        return sch
    #Create schema and geometry dynamically from passed dparameters
    my_schema = schema_setter(feat_type)
    my_geom = geom_setter(ls)
    wr_dict = {'geometry': mapping(my_geom),'properties': att_dict} 
    with fiona.open(path="TestShapefile\my_shp_clean1.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
        output.write(wr_dict)
```

Function parameters explanation- e.g.point writing case

```
ls = [(488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)]
att_dict = {'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'junction_shape': '30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A'}
feat_type = 'junction'
```

And  `my_schema` is as below.

```
my_schema = {'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'intLanes': 'str', 'y': 'str', 'incLanes': 'str', 'junction_shape': 'str', 'x': 'str', 'type': 'str', 'id': 'str'}}
```

**But without no success, it creates shapefile but i think it is corrupt since can not open in arcmap but shown error like *`could not open the specified file`***

What i want:

Function `single_geom_writer` will take three parameters
1) list of geometry(`ls`)
2) shapefile attribute dictionary(`att_dict`)
3) a flag(`feat_type`) to control to be written shapefile if it will be polyline or point.

The `single_geom_writer` will automatically determine if the passed argument(ls) is point or polyline and will create shapely geometry object.Passed `att_dict` is just attribute of shapefile that will match following selected `schema` . Based on passed `feat_type` this function will set `schema` which will match previuos attribute dictionary.

---

**Problem:**

---

This code-

```
with fiona.open(path="TestShapefile\my_shp_clean1.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
    output.write(wr_dict)
```

is not writing geometry even no exception is being raised- created shapefile is blank.

Edit:

See working and not working code-

```
#Working
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
my_schema={'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'index': 'str', 'length': 'str', 'speed': 'str', 'id': 'str', 'width': 'str'}}
wr_dict = {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'index': '0', 'length': '49.79', 'speed': '13.89', 'id': 'A-A0_0', 'width': '3.25'}}
with fiona.open("my_shp_clean121.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
    output.write(wr_dict)

#Not working
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
my_schema={'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'intLanes': 'str', 'y': 'str', 'incLanes': 'str', 'junction_shape': 'str', 'x': 'str', 'type': 'str', 'id': 'str'}}
wr_dict = {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'junction_shape': '30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A'}}
with fiona.open("my_shp_clean12221.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
    output.write(wr_dict)
```

---

**EDIT:**
QGIS opens the created shapefile but it is blank!
Any help is welcome.

Comment: It's *very* difficult to tell from what you have posted, but if you are generating shapefiles with more than one topology class, then the files are not legal.  Please **edit** your question to use a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), containing **only** the code needed to demonstrate the behavior, with a complete description of inputs and a hexadecimal dump (`od -t x1`) of the single-feature output files.

Comment: What is `wr_dict` ?

Comment: @Vince Should i post the full code?

Comment: @gene wr_dict is a just dictionary (*see the function*) that will be written to the shapefile..e.g. {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'junction_shape': '30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A'}}

Comment: see below for the result

Comment: Not more code, **less** code.   The *minimum* code required to exhibit the behavior.

Comment: But the problem is no exception is raised rather blank shapefile gets created.

Comment: I edited the question. Please see **ONLY** Problem section.@Vince could you elaborate what means `topology class`. Thanks

Comment: The problem section of your question does not have a working code snippet in it.  I recommend that you also include the line that sets `wr_dict` and then some hardwired values for any variables that it uses.  Besides that just include the `import` statements to give anyone with Fiona installed a simple test that they can run to see what you are describing.

Comment: @PolyGeo Ah! `(wr_dict)` is upshot of several operations (not a single) that is generated dynamically from the passed parameters, that is in the above code- Thanks

Comment: Try to hardwire it to something that you think/know should work, and then compare that to what is being written by that other non-GIS code from the "`lxml` library that generates some dictionary".  If you can isolate it to `fiona` (GIS/spatial library) and isolate it from `lxml` (IT/XML library - better researched at [so]) then you have something that is on-topic for here.

Comment: Thanks-Could you tell if fiona can write unicode attribute to shapefile- I will hardwire, you always help.. I tested lxml (using BP) giving write dictionary and list- i am afraid of unicode writing capability of fiona. I tested `wr_dict` is just fiona-compatible  `{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'junction_shape': '30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A'}}` so lxml seems ok to go with.

Comment: Thanks ALL i found the solution-silly,silly mistake i.e. i  exceeded the shapefile name length (10 char) in `'junction_shape'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the shapefile

```
import fiona
from fiona.crs import from_epsg
my_schema={'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': {'intLanes': 'str', 'y': 'str', 'incLanes': 'str', 'junction_shape': 'str', 'x': 'str', 'type': 'str', 'id': 'str'}}
wr_dict = {'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'properties': {'intLanes': ':A_0_0 :A_1_0', 'junction_shape': '30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78', 'incLanes': 'B-A_0 A0-A_0', 'y': '39.18', 'x': '31.72', 'type': 'unregulated', 'id': 'A'}}
with fiona.open("my_shp_clean1.shp", mode='w', driver='ESRI Shapefile', schema=my_schema,crs =from_epsg(32632)) as output:
     output.write(wr_dict)
```

Opening the resulting shapefile

```
import fiona
c = fiona.open("my_shp_clean1.shp")
c.schema
{'geometry': 'Point', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'intLanes', 'str:80'), (u'y', 'str:80'), (u'incLanes', 'str:80'), (u'junction_s', 'str:80'), (u'x', 'str:80'), (u'type', 'str:80'), (u'id', 'str:80')])}
c.crs
{'init': u'epsg:32632'}
c.next()
{'geometry': {'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': (488901.97760411515, 5078198.250875515)}, 'type': 'Feature', 'id': '0', 'properties': OrderedDict([(u'intLanes', u':A_0_0 :A_1_0'), (u'y', u'39.18'), (u'incLanes', u'B-A_0 A0-A_0'), (u'junction_s', u'30.62,42.35 33.90,36.62 28.77,40.78'), (u'x', u'31.72'), (u'type', u'unregulated'), (u'id', u'A')])}
```

The result seems ok

Secondly, when I open the resulting shapefile with QGIS, there is apparently no problem:

[image]

Comment: look at my script to create the shapefile with your resulting data

Comment: Ah! i am getting blank shapefile even when i run simple-code your i.e  first code.What happened

Comment: Therefore, the problem is your Fiona installation

Comment: Yeah! i just tested fiona is so healthy and works superb with other code.

Comment: does 'junction_shape' automatically changed to 'junction_s'?In my case whole process gets corrupted and blank file gets created.